# Vist64 crash Bluescreen 1000007e

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, crash

My computer (Dell Precision T7400) keeps crashing. Usually the screen and input devices freezes, but I've also gotten a bluescreen:

```
Problemsignatur:
  Problemhändelsens namn:   BlueScreen
  OS-version:   6.0.6001.2.1.0.256.6
  Språkvariant-ID:  1053

Ytterligare information om problemet:
  BCCode:   1000007e
  BCP1: FFFFFFFFC0000005
  BCP2: FFFFF800021C9B81
  BCP3: FFFFFA6001DDB798
  BCP4: FFFFFA6001DDB170
  OS Version:   6_0_6001
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product:  256_1

Filer som hjälper till att beskriva problemet:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\Mini090209-01.dmp
  C:\Users\Niels Bosma\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-74958-0.sysdata.xml
  C:\Users\Niels Bosma\AppData\Local\Temp\WER2960.tmp.version.txt

Läs vår sekretesspolicy:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=50163&clcid=0x041d
```

(sorry for the swedish)

The event log doesn't show anything.

Running windbg gets me:

```
0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M (1000007e)
This is a very common bugcheck.  Usually the exception address pinpoints
the driver/function that caused the problem.  Always note this address
as well as the link date of the driver/image that contains this address.
Some common problems are exception code 0x80000003.  This means a hard
coded breakpoint or assertion was hit, but this system was booted
/NODEBUG.  This is not supposed to happen as developers should never have
hardcoded breakpoints in retail code, but ...
If this happens, make sure a debugger gets connected, and the
system is booted /DEBUG.  This will let us see why this breakpoint is
happening.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffffffc0000005, The exception code that was not handled
Arg2: fffff800021c9b81, The address that the exception occurred at
Arg3: fffffa6001ddb798, Exception Record Address
Arg4: fffffa6001ddb170, Context Record Address

Debugging Details:
------------------


EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Instruktionen p  0x%08lx refererade till minnet p  0x%08lx. Det gick inte att utf ra en minnes tg rd. F ljande fel returnerades: The memory could not be %s.

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!IopFreeRelationList+21
fffff800`021c9b81 488b3e          mov     rdi,qword ptr [rsi]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  fffffa6001ddb798 -- (.exr 0xfffffa6001ddb798)
ExceptionAddress: fffff800021c9b81 (nt!IopFreeRelationList+0x0000000000000021)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000010
Attempt to read from address 0000000000000010

CONTEXT:  fffffa6001ddb170 -- (.cxr 0xfffffa6001ddb170)
rax=fffffa80039b4b01 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=fffffa80039b4b01 rsi=0000000000000010 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff800021c9b81 rsp=fffffa6001ddb9d0 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=fffffa800654dad0  r9=5000c5f90e000000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=00000000000007ff r12=fffff80001ffbb20 r13=fffffa8009aec750
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000001
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
nt!IopFreeRelationList+0x21:
fffff800`021c9b81 488b3e          mov     rdi,qword ptr [rsi] ds:002b:00000000`00000010=????????????????
Resetting default scope

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Instruktionen p  0x%08lx refererade till minnet p  0x%08lx. Det gick inte att utf ra en minnes tg rd. F ljande fel returnerades: The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  0000000000000010

READ_ADDRESS: GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from fffff80002028080
 0000000000000010 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!IopFreeRelationList+21
fffff800`021c9b81 488b3e          mov     rdi,qword ptr [rsi]

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x7E

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80002233417 to fffff800021c9b81

STACK_TEXT:  
fffffa60`01ddb9d0 fffff800`02233417 : fffffa80`0654dad0 00000000`00000001 fffffa80`05912060 fffff800`0206738c : nt!IopFreeRelationList+0x21
fffffa60`01ddba10 fffff800`02233555 : fffffa80`0654dad0 fffffa80`09aec750 fffffa80`09aec750 00000000`00000000 : nt!PnpDelayedRemoveWorker+0x97
fffffa60`01ddba60 fffff800`01f2ec69 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`0726bd00 : nt!PnpChainDereferenceComplete+0x115
fffffa60`01ddbaa0 fffff800`02237d79 : 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`05912000 fffffa80`08ad22e0 00000000`00000001 : nt!PnpIsChainDereferenced+0xc9
fffffa60`01ddbb20 fffff800`02237ffc : fffffa60`01ddbcf8 fffffa80`042e4400 fffffa80`039b4b00 fffffa80`00000000 : nt!PnpProcessQueryRemoveAndEject+0xf99
fffffa60`01ddbc70 fffff800`021386c7 : 00000000`00000001 fffffa80`042e4410 fffff880`0eb40980 00000000`00000000 : nt!PnpProcessTargetDeviceEvent+0x4c
fffffa60`01ddbca0 fffff800`01e5ce4a : fffff800`02064494 fffff880`0eb40980 fffff800`01f928f8 fffffa80`039b4bb0 : nt! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'+0x4a314
fffffa60`01ddbcf0 fffff800`02074573 : fffffa80`042e4410 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`039b4bb0 00000000`00000080 : nt!ExpWorkerThread+0x11a
fffffa60`01ddbd50 fffff800`01e8bff6 : fffffa60`01bd2180 fffffa80`039b4bb0 fffffa60`01bdbd40 00000000`00000001 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x57
fffffa60`01ddbd80 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x16


SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!IopFreeRelationList+21

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4a67e1a0

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xfffffa6001ddb170 ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7E_nt!IopFreeRelationList+21

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7E_nt!IopFreeRelationList+21

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have **Update for Microsoft Windows (KB973879)** installed? It has a [defect that results in a `SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED` bug check](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975070/). Unfortunately, [KB975070](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975070/) doesn't contain enough information to identify whether it's the same problem, but Googling for `IopFreeRelationList` turns up several forum threads with the same track trace and suggestions to remove KB973879.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a `minidump` in place.
You could trace this down with [WinDbg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg).
Here is [an article reference](http://www.networkworld.com/news/2005/041105-windows-crash.html) to do that.

---

Do all crashes have the same report?
Here is another [frequent crash example](http://www.techsupportforum.com/1808835-post2.html).

You could also check with the [System File Checker scan](http://www.updatexp.com/scannow-sfc.html),
I think it works on Vista64 too,

```
sfc /scannow
```

And there is also the [System Health Report](http://www.ghacks.net/2007/02/28/generate-a-system-health-report-in-windows-vista/) option.

I guess, you have already confirmed driver updates...
You last resort would be a system recovery (from your install CD or the OEM partition).

Comment: Did that, seems problem with ntkrnkmp.exe... so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Verify for Windows Update history if it hasn't installed a hardware driver at the time that the problem started, and if so then roll it back, and get the latest driver from the manufacturer's web site.
Also check if you've lately installed any new product that might be causing this.

If you're not sure, try to see if the problem happens when you boot in safe mode. This might help to narrow it down to either a driver/microsoft or an application.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack you can see that a PNP device is causing this, you can try to disconnect (pull the cable out or remove internal hardware) and disable (in the device manager) as many devices as you can and see if the problem still occurs.

Unless you are an expert in WinDBG there is no other way to debug this in my opinion.